# Remove duplicates in O(n) by hand

Tags: algorithm

I need to remove all duplicates in a list, but only if the item in list a is the same in list b aswell. This is my current code, but at 100k items it's taking literal days, is there a fast way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

```
  List<int> ind = new List<int>();
            List<int> used = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j&&!used.Contains(i))
                    {
                        if (a[j] == a[i] && b[i] == b[j])
                        {
                            ind.Add(j);
                            used.Add(j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            List<string> s2 = new List<string>();
            List<string> a2 = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!ind.Contains(i))
                {
                    s2.Add(a[i]);
                    a2.Add(b[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Looks like incorrect Java to me.

Comment: Actually it looks like (possibly) correct C# code to me, but I wanted to ask to be certain.

Comment: language agnostic preferably, but yea C#

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Wow, C# and Java look very similar!

Comment: It is very weird in your example that variables `i` and `j` run through list `a`, but are also used to access elements in list `b`. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

The key to many such problems is the correct data structure. To avoid duplicates, you need to use Sets, as they remove duplicates automatically.

Here is the code in Java, I hope it is similar in C#:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

class Duplicates
{
    static List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    static final int SIZE = 100_000;
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 1000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // populate the lists with random values for testing
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            list1.add(r.nextInt(MAX_VALUE));
            list2.add(r.nextInt(MAX_VALUE));
        }
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);

        // items that are in both lists
        Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>(set1);
        intersection.retainAll(set2);

        Set<Integer> notSeenYet = new HashSet<>(intersection);

        List<Integer> list1Unique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int n: list1)
        {
            if(intersection.contains(n)) // we may have to skip this one
            {
                if(notSeenYet.contains(n)) // no, don't skip, it's the first occurrence
                {
                    notSeenYet.remove(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            list1Unique.add(n);
        }
        System.out.println("list 1 contains "+list1Unique.size()+" values after removing all duplicates that are also in list 2");

    }

}
```

It takes less than a second for 100k values.

*Output*

> list 1 contains 99591 values after removing all duplicates that are
>   also in list 2

Comment: that only works using duplicates in a single list, i need to compare two lists side by side, I may just concatenate the two with a character I know won't be in either, put in a hashset then split it afterwards

Comment: Why not make it into a single list first? In C++ you could just make a list/set of pair(a, b)

Comment: @HansOlsson: Maybe I understood the asker differently. I interpreted his question as "remove all duplicates from list 1, but only if that value is also in list 2".

Comment: @KonradHöffner I also thought that as first, but the original code and the comment by the asker seemed to indicate that it meant "if the value in the second list at the same place are also duplicates". I maybe mistaken, it all seems unclear to me

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general algorithm to consider.  We can start by sorting both lists in ascending order.  Using a good sorting algorithm such as merge sort, this would take `O(NlgN)` time, where `N` is the length of the list.  Once we have paid this penalty, we need only maintain two pointers in each of the lists.  The general algorithm would basically involve walking up both lists, searching for duplicates in the first `a` list, should the value in question match the pointer into the `b` list.  If there be a match, then duplicates would be removed from the `a` list, otherwise we keep walking until reaching the end of the `a` list.  This process would be only `O(N)`, making the biggest penalty the initial sort, which is `O(NlgN)`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `HashSet`.

First, iterate through the list `b` and add all elements into the HashSet.

Then, iterate through each element of the list `a`. When you visit an element, ask the HashSet if it already contains that element. If if doesn't, it's a new element, so just keep it. If it does, it is a duplicate and you can remove it from `a`.

HashSets can perform the `Do you have this element?` question in O(1), so for the whole list, you have O(n).

For more information, check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Good, but now this algorithm would remove not only duplicates from list `a`, but all elements there (not `n-1`, but `n` of them).

Comment: The op said: "I need to remove all duplicates in `a` only if the item in `a` is the same in list `b`". Once you have a hash will all elements of `b`, you can remove all the elements `a` which are also in `b`, but I don't see how this is going to remove all elements in `a`, since if an element is in `a` and not in `b`, it will be kept.

Comment: You don't have to iterate through the list to add to the `HashSet`. Check out `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)

Answer (score 1):

To "remove duplicates" I understand to mean "from n identical items, leave the first and remove the remaining n - 1". If so then this is the algorithm:

Convert list `b` to set `B`. Also introduce set `A_dup`. Run through list `a` and for each item:

- if item is found in `A_dup` then remove it from `a`,
- else if item is found in set `B` then add it to `A_dup`.
- Repeat.

Checking for existence in sets (both `A_dup` and `B`) is O(1) operation, also to add new item in the set. So, you're left with iterating through list `a`, which in total gives us O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is find distinct pairs, right?

If so, you can do that in one line using `Zip` and `Distinct` and a C# Tuple (or use an anonymous type).

```
  var result = a.Zip(b, (x,y) => (x, y)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> dupliKhaneList = new ArrayList<>();
        dupliKhaneList.add("Vaquar");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Khan");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Vaquar");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Vaquar");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Khan");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Vaquar");
        dupliKhaneList.add("Zidan");

        // Solution 1 if want to remove in list 
        List<String> uniqueList = dupliKhaneList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("DupliKhane =>  " + dupliKhaneList);
        System.out.println("Unique 1 =>  " + uniqueList);

        // Solution 2 if want to remove using 2 list
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("Vaquar");
        list1.add("Khan");
        list1.add("Vaquar");
        list1.add("Vaquar");
        list1.add("Khan");
        list1.add("Vaquar");
        list1.add("Zidan");

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        list2.add("Zidan");

        System.out.println("list1 =>  " + list1);
        System.out.println("list2 =>  " + list2);

        list1.removeAll(list2);

        System.out.println("removeAll duplicate  =>  " + list1);
    }
}
```

Results :

```
DupliKhane =>  [Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar, Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar, Zidan]
Unique 1 =>  [Vaquar, Khan, Zidan]
list1 =>  [Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar, Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar, Zidan]
list2 =>  [Zidan]
removeAll duplicate  =>  [Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar, Vaquar, Khan, Vaquar]
```